# How to center TextBox element inside Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I'm developing WP8 app for my own needs and want it to have small live tile with text.
Since small tile cannot display text, I'm generating appropriate image with needed text.
Here is the code:

```
WriteableBitmap bmpSmall = new WriteableBitmap(159, 159);
var grid = new Grid();
grid.Width = bmpSmall.PixelWidth;
grid.Height = bmpSmall.PixelHeight;

var background = new Canvas();
background.Width = bmpSmall.PixelWidth;
background.Height = bmpSmall.PixelHeight;

SolidColorBrush backColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]);
background.Background = backColor;

var textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "qwerty";
textBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
textBlock.FontSize = 28;
textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
bmpSmall.Render(background, null);
bmpSmall.Render(grid, null);
bmpSmall.Invalidate();

using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream imageStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/Shared/ShellContent/smallTile.jpg", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isf))
    {
        bmpSmall.SaveJpeg(imageStream, 159, 159, 0, 100);
    }
}

ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
FlipTileData tileData = new FlipTileData();
tileData.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/smallTile.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
tile.Update(tileData);
```

And result looks like:

[image]

As you see, text is aligned to top left corner. The question is "Why"? Since I'd set `textBlock.HorizontalAlignment` and `textBlock.VerticalAlignment` - I expect it in the center of the image.
For example the following XAML looks like you can expect and like I need:

```
<Grid Width="159" Height="159">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="28" Foreground="White">qwerty</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

What did I miss? How can I center text?

Comment: Why are you creating the elements in the code-behind anyways? I'd be cleaner to do it in XAML.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I need to generate that image dynamically. The "qwerty" text is just for example. Is it possible to do this with XAML? I'm not c# programmer actually, and this is my first application with all these MS technologies. In fact, I'm not programmer at all, I'm sysadmin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following code a try:

```
       WriteableBitmap bmpSmall = new WriteableBitmap(159, 159);
        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.Width = bmpSmall.PixelWidth;
        grid.Height = bmpSmall.PixelHeight;

        var background = new Canvas();
        background.Width = bmpSmall.PixelWidth;
        background.Height = bmpSmall.PixelHeight;

        SolidColorBrush backColor = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]);
        background.Background = backColor;

        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.Width = bmpSmall.PixelWidth;

        textBlock.Text = "qwerty";
        textBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        textBlock.FontSize = 28;
        textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        textBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        grid.Children.Add(background);
        grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
        grid.Measure(new Size(bmpSmall.PixelWidth, bmpSmall.PixelHeight));
        grid.Arrange(new Rect(0,0,bmpSmall.PixelWidth, bmpSmall.PixelHeight));
        grid.UpdateLayout();
        bmpSmall.Render(grid, null);
        bmpSmall.Invalidate();
```

I set the `TextBlock` width to the same as the rest of the tile, and set `HorizontalAlignment` to stretch, so that control would take up the whole width of the tile. Then I set the `TextAlignment` property to `TextAlignment.Center`, in order to center the text. Hope that helps!

Edit: Apparently for writable bitmaps, you must do the measure/arrange/layout steps yourself in order to render controls as you would think they should be rendered. Give this updated code a try, it should work this time!

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this is only half solution. It centers text horizontally, but not vertically. Also `HorizontalAlignment` is not needed in this case, since textBlock is already stretched to the width of tile. Actually this is what I'm using now to center text horizontally + margin property to center text vertically. But I still cannot understand and want to know - why `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties do not work.

Comment: Ah, I missed the vertical centering part - read my updated answer, it should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This works! Also tests show that only Arrange call is needed to align the text block.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` for grid also. Currently grid is only of size of its content i.e `textblock`.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Actually the grid has fixed size 159x159. Anyway, I've tried to add `grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;` and `grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;` but no effect

Answer (score 0):

After copying your code into an empty WPF application, I'm afraid to tell you that your code works just fine:

[image]

All I did was to set the `Grid.Background` to red and the `TextBlock.Background` to black to clarify the situation:

```
<Grid Width="159" Height="159">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="28" 
        Foreground="White">qwerty</TextBlock>
```

Therefore, I can only assume that you have a problem elsewhere in your code.

UPDATE >>>

Sorry, you're right, I *did* misunderstand you. However, after testing your `C#` code, the story is just the same:

[image]

This *might* look like the same image, but it *actually* comes from *your* `C#` code... I made a couple of little changes, but nothing that affected the position of the `TextBlock`:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Background = Brushes.Red;
grid.Width = grid.Height = 159.0;
TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
textBlock.Text = "qwerty";
textBlock.Background = Brushes.Black;
textBlock.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
textBlock.FontSize = 28;
textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.White;
grid.Children.Add(textBlock);
this.Content = grid;
```

If you put this code into a new WPF project, you'll see that it works just fine, so that only leaves your `WriteableBitmap` object as the culprit of this problem... what are you using that for? If you're just adding it to your UI, then you can simply add the controls to the `Window` directly.

Comment: Excuse me. But I don't think you understand the question. Probably my fault, since my English far not perfect and not my native language.
XAML code works fine and displays everything as it should. But when I'm trying to do the same from c#, it ignores `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties. And textBlock is aligned to top left corner.